# Using VB, is there a way to capture the FTP results from a CMD window?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual studio 2012 and writing in VB. I want to find a way to launch a batch file for an FTP download or upload, have the progress show in the CMD window and record the results of the transfer times to a textbox.

Any help is appreciated.

FTP batch Scripts are as follows:

Filename: FTP_1M_Download.bat:

```
    @Echo off
    cd (Folder name here)
    ftp -s:FTP_1M_Download_s.bat
```

Filename: FTP_1M_Download_s.bat:

```
    open (FTP Address here)
    username
    password
    hash
    bin
    be
    get down_1M.zip
```

Comment: Use `FtpWebRequest` via `WebRequest.Create()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some un-edited utility code I use to run RoboCopy using ProcessStartInfo. It captures the output stream (the code doesn't do anything with it in this case.)

I use the Kellerman SFTP library - works great, not expensive.

```
  Sub RunRobo(ByVal SD As String, ByVal DD As String, ByVal Job As String, ByRef Out As String, ByRef Err As String)
    ' runs RoboCopy and returns log text 
    ' typical job: "*.* /V /NDL /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /NP /R:0 /W:0 "
    Try
        Application.DoEvents()
        Dim sParams As String = SD & " " & DD & " " & Job
        'If Not ShowHeadFoot Then sParams &= " /NJH /NJS"

        ' Set start information.
        Dim start_info As New ProcessStartInfo("RoboCopy", sParams)
        start_info.UseShellExecute = False
        start_info.CreateNoWindow = True
        start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        start_info.RedirectStandardError = True

        ' Make the process and set its start information.
        Dim proc As New Process()
        proc.StartInfo = start_info

        ' Start the process.
        proc.Start()

        ' Attach to stdout and stderr.
        Dim std_out As System.IO.StreamReader = proc.StandardOutput()
        Dim std_err As System.IO.StreamReader = proc.StandardError()

        ' Display the results.
        Out = std_out.ReadToEnd()
        Err = std_err.ReadToEnd()

        'Dim aLines() As String = sOut.Split(vbCrLf) ' if no header/footer creates array of file info

        ' more generic would be to return via params
        'txtStreetsErr.Text = sErr
        'txtStreetsOut.Text = sOut

        Try
            std_out.Close()
            std_err.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Try
            proc.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Error during RoboCopy")
    Finally
        'Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But i keep getting stuck at: Out = std_out.ReadToEnd()

Comment: OUT and ERR are ByRef variables passed into the utility Sub. Declare Out and Err as strings in your code and it should work.